# Add certificate into Dockerfile (rhel7)

Tags: docker, ssl-certificate, dockerfile

I use this feature and I need to add certificate for proxy into dockerfile (as command)
I read different resources but it all were about ubuntu, is it simular or not?

How can I automatically add cert when docker try build.
I think I need ADD command, but what kind of folder I need to put into?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It took us to use COPY command and RUN :

for rhel7:

```
COPY your-xert.cer /etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors/
RUN update-ca-trust
```

for centos

```
COPY your-xert.cer /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/
RUN update-ca-certificates
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `COPY` in your Dockerfile to include a file from your local system into the container.

Here is the documentation for syntax:

[Dockerfile reference - COPY](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy)

Here is an example Dockerfile with many elements that I like to refer to when needed:

[Example dockerfile](https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/blob/fc3e856313423dc2d6a8d74cfd6b678582090fc7/5.7/Dockerfile)

Paste your Dockerfile and commands used if you still have questions.